# Consuming a web service with a parent child relationship VB or C#

Tags: c#, xml, vb.net, wsdl

I am hoping I am missing something really simple here.

I have a need to update a web service with a list of medications that a particular patient is on. I am sending the ID of the patient as well as a list of the medications. I have been provided with the following WSDL

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

-<wsdl:definitions name="GOLDSessionResponseService" 
xmlns:wsa="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing" 
xmlns:wsaw="http://www.w3.org/2006/05/addressing/wsdl" 
xmlns:wsa10="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" 
xmlns:tns="http://City.health.xxx.au/" 
xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" 
xmlns:soap12="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap12/" 
xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" 
xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" 
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
xmlns:wsp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy" 
xmlns:msc="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/12/wsdl/contract" 
xmlns:wsap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing/policy" 
xmlns:wsx="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/mex" 
xmlns:wsam="http://www.w3.org/2007/05/addressing/metadata" 
xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" 
targetNamespace="http://City.health.xxx.au/">

-<wsdl:types>

-<xs:schema targetNamespace="http://City.health.xxx.au/" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified">

  <xs:import namespace="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/City.Services.GOLD"/>


  -<xs:element name="SessionCompleted">


    -<xs:complexType>


      -<xs:sequence>

        <xs:element type="q1:SessionCompletionRequest" name="request" xmlns:q1="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/City.Services.GOLD" nillable="true" minOccurs="0"/>

      </xs:sequence>

    </xs:complexType>

  </xs:element>


  -<xs:element name="SessionCompletedResponse">


    -<xs:complexType>


      -<xs:sequence>

        <xs:element type="q2:SessionCompletionResponse" name="SessionCompletedResult" nillable="true" minOccurs="0" xmlns:q2="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/City.Services.GOLD"/>

      </xs:sequence>

    </xs:complexType>

  </xs:element>


  -<xs:element name="UpdateMedications">


    -<xs:complexType>


      -<xs:sequence>

        <xs:element type="q3:UpdateMedicationsRequest" name="request" nillable="true" minOccurs="0" xmlns:q3="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/City.Services.GOLD"/>

      </xs:sequence>

    </xs:complexType>

  </xs:element>


  -<xs:element name="UpdateMedicationsResponse">


    -<xs:complexType>


      -<xs:sequence>

        <xs:element type="q4:UpdateMedicationsResponse" name="UpdateMedicationsResult" nillable="true" minOccurs="0" xmlns:q4="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/City.Services.GOLD"/>

      </xs:sequence>

    </xs:complexType>

  </xs:element>

</xs:schema>


-<xs:schema xmlns:tns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/" targetNamespace="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="qualified">

  <xs:element type="xs:anyType" name="anyType" nillable="true"/>

  <xs:element type="xs:anyURI" name="anyURI" nillable="true"/>

  <xs:element type="xs:base64Binary" name="base64Binary" nillable="true"/>

  <xs:element type="xs:boolean" name="boolean" nillable="true"/>

  <xs:element type="xs:byte" name="byte" nillable="true"/>

  <xs:element type="xs:dateTime" name="dateTime" nillable="true"/>

  <xs:element type="xs:decimal" name="decimal" nillable="true"/>

  <xs:element type="xs:double" name="double" nillable="true"/>

  <xs:element type="xs:float" name="float" nillable="true"/>

  <xs:element type="xs:int" name="int" nillable="true"/>

  <xs:element type="xs:long" name="long" nillable="true"/>

  <xs:element type="xs:QName" name="QName" nillable="true"/>

  <xs:element type="xs:short" name="short" nillable="true"/>

  <xs:element type="xs:string" name="string" nillable="true"/>

  <xs:element type="xs:unsignedByte" name="unsignedByte" nillable="true"/>

  <xs:element type="xs:unsignedInt" name="unsignedInt" nillable="true"/>

  <xs:element type="xs:unsignedLong" name="unsignedLong" nillable="true"/>

  <xs:element type="xs:unsignedShort" name="unsignedShort" nillable="true"/>

  <xs:element type="tns:char" name="char" nillable="true"/>


  -<xs:simpleType name="char">

    <xs:restriction base="xs:int"/>

  </xs:simpleType>

  <xs:element type="tns:duration" name="duration" nillable="true"/>


  -<xs:simpleType name="duration">


    -<xs:restriction base="xs:duration">

      <xs:pattern value="\-?P(\d*D)?(T(\d*H)?(\d*M)?(\d*(\.\d*)?S)?)?"/>

      <xs:minInclusive value="-P10675199DT2H48M5.4775808S"/>

      <xs:maxInclusive value="P10675199DT2H48M5.4775807S"/>

    </xs:restriction>

  </xs:simpleType>

  <xs:element type="tns:guid" name="guid" nillable="true"/>


  -<xs:simpleType name="guid">


    -<xs:restriction base="xs:string">

      <xs:pattern value="[\da-fA-F]{8}-[\da-fA-F]{4}-[\da-fA-F]{4}-[\da-fA-F]{4}-[\da-fA-F]{12}"/>

    </xs:restriction>

  </xs:simpleType>

  <xs:attribute type="xs:QName" name="FactoryType"/>

  <xs:attribute type="xs:ID" name="Id"/>

  <xs:attribute type="xs:IDREF" name="Ref"/>

</xs:schema>


-<xs:schema xmlns:tns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/City.Services.GOLD" targetNamespace="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/City.Services.GOLD" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified">


  -<xs:complexType name="SessionCompletionRequest">


    -<xs:sequence>

      <xs:element type="xs:dateTime" name="AppointmentDateTime" minOccurs="0"/>

      <xs:element type="xs:dateTime" name="NextAppointmentDateTime" minOccurs="0"/>

      <xs:element type="xs:int" name="PatientId" minOccurs="0"/>

      <xs:element type="xs:string" name="SessionLetter" nillable="true" minOccurs="0"/>

      <xs:element type="xs:int" name="SessionNumber" minOccurs="0"/>

      <xs:element type="xs:string" name="Status" nillable="true" minOccurs="0"/>

    </xs:sequence>

  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:element type="tns:SessionCompletionRequest" name="SessionCompletionRequest" nillable="true"/>


  -<xs:complexType name="SessionCompletionResponse">


    -<xs:sequence>

      <xs:element type="xs:string" name="ErrorMessage" nillable="true" minOccurs="0"/>

      <xs:element type="xs:boolean" name="Success" minOccurs="0"/>

    </xs:sequence>

  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:element type="tns:SessionCompletionResponse" name="SessionCompletionResponse" nillable="true"/>


  -<xs:complexType name="UpdateMedicationsRequest">


    -<xs:sequence>

      <xs:element type="tns:Medication" name="Medications" nillable="true" minOccurs="0"/>

      <xs:element type="xs:int" name="PatientId" minOccurs="0"/>

    </xs:sequence>

  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:element type="tns:UpdateMedicationsRequest" name="UpdateMedicationsRequest" nillable="true"/>


  -<xs:complexType name="Medication">


    -<xs:sequence>

      <xs:element type="xs:string" name="BrandName" nillable="true" minOccurs="0"/>

      <xs:element type="xs:string" name="Generic" nillable="true" minOccurs="0"/>

    </xs:sequence>

  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:element type="tns:Medication" name="Medication" nillable="true"/>


  -<xs:complexType name="UpdateMedicationsResponse">


    -<xs:sequence>

      <xs:element type="xs:string" name="ErrorMessage" nillable="true" minOccurs="0"/>

      <xs:element type="xs:boolean" name="Success" minOccurs="0"/>

    </xs:sequence>

  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:element type="tns:UpdateMedicationsResponse" name="UpdateMedicationsResponse" nillable="true"/>

</xs:schema>
```

```
-<wsdl:message name="IGOLDSessionResponseService_SessionCompleted_InputMessage">

    <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:SessionCompleted"/>

</wsdl:message>


-<wsdl:message name="IGOLDSessionResponseService_SessionCompleted_OutputMessage">

    <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:SessionCompletedResponse"/>

</wsdl:message>


-<wsdl:message name="IGOLDSessionResponseService_UpdateMedications_InputMessage">

    <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:UpdateMedications"/>

</wsdl:message>


-<wsdl:message name="IGOLDSessionResponseService_UpdateMedications_OutputMessage">

    <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:UpdateMedicationsResponse"/>

</wsdl:message>


-<wsdl:portType name="IGOLDSessionResponseService">


-<wsdl:operation name="SessionCompleted">

  <wsdl:input message="tns:IGOLDSessionResponseService_SessionCompleted_InputMessage" wsaw:Action="http://City.health.xxx.au/IGOLDSessionResponseService/SessionCompleted"/>

  <wsdl:output message="tns:IGOLDSessionResponseService_SessionCompleted_OutputMessage" wsaw:Action="http://City.health.xxx.au/IGOLDSessionResponseService/SessionCompletedResponse"/>

</wsdl:operation>


-<wsdl:operation name="UpdateMedications">

  <wsdl:input message="tns:IGOLDSessionResponseService_UpdateMedications_InputMessage" wsaw:Action="http://City.health.xxx.au/IGOLDSessionResponseService/UpdateMedications"/>

  <wsdl:output message="tns:IGOLDSessionResponseService_UpdateMedications_OutputMessage" wsaw:Action="http://City.health.xxx.au/IGOLDSessionResponseService/UpdateMedicationsResponse"/>

</wsdl:operation>
```

```
-<wsdl:binding type="tns:IGOLDSessionResponseService" name="BasicHttpBinding_IGOLDSessionResponseService">

<soap:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>


-<wsdl:operation name="SessionCompleted">

  <soap:operation style="document" soapAction="http://City.health.xxx.au/IGOLDSessionResponseService/SessionCompleted"/>


  -<wsdl:input>

    <soap:body use="literal"/>

  </wsdl:input>


  -<wsdl:output>

    <soap:body use="literal"/>

  </wsdl:output>

</wsdl:operation>


-<wsdl:operation name="UpdateMedications">

  <soap:operation style="document" soapAction="http://City.health.xxx.au/IGOLDSessionResponseService/UpdateMedications"/>


  -<wsdl:input>

    <soap:body use="literal"/>

  </wsdl:input>


  -<wsdl:output>

    <soap:body use="literal"/>

  </wsdl:output>

</wsdl:operation>

</wsdl:binding>


-<wsdl:service name="GOLDSessionResponseService">


-<wsdl:port name="BasicHttpBinding_IGOLDSessionResponseService" binding="tns:BasicHttpBinding_IGOLDSessionResponseService">

  <soap:address location="http://services.City.simient.com/GOLD/GOLDSessionResponseService.svc"/>

</wsdl:port>
```

I have added the WebReference to my project and tried to consume the services. I am encountering an error when trying to link the medications to the patientid.

The code is displayed below:

```
Dim medadd As Services.UpdateMedicationsRequest = New Services.UpdateMedicationsRequest()
Dim medresponse As Services.UpdateMedicationsResponse = New Services.UpdateMedicationsResponse()

Dim medlist As Medication = New Medication()


medadd.PatientId = CInt(patientid)
medadd.PatientIdSpecified = True
medlist.BrandName = "testbrand"
medlist.Generic = "testgeneric"


medadd.Medications = medlist??????


medresponse = client.UpdateMedications(medadd)
```

I am getting stuck at trying to add the medications to the parent class.

Any suggestions would be much appreciated

Joe

Answer (score 0):

medadd.Medications is a collection of Medication element so you have to use a specific add method and not just assign a medication element to medications

it should be something like

```
medadd.Medications.Add(medlist);
```

if the Medications is not yet assigned (nil) then you have to create a new empty list of Medication before performing the add operation

```
Dim medications As New List(Of Medication)();
medications.Add(medlist);
medadd.Medications = medications;
```

Another thing that can generate some issue is the `minOccurs = 0` for the Medications. It should be `minOccurs = 1`

Comment: Hi, thanks for your feedback and it has helped me along the way. However your last line of code produces an error for me 'Value of type List( of Medication) cannot be converted to Medication() , I hope you can provide me with a suggestion for this.

Comment: Which is the type of `medadd.Medications`?

Comment: medadd.Medications is of type Medication. Does the problem lie with the wsdl? Thanks so much for helping on this :)

Comment: see my latest modification about minOccurs

Comment: OK, I will take that up with the developer of the web service. There is the possibility of having 0 medications to send but in that case it would be best not to send at all! Thanks once again

Comment: if it is 0 then you can use nil